# ValueError:; Error when checking input: expected flatten_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (940682, 2)

Tags: python, tensorflow, dotnetnuke

**I'm training a DNN model in python.
and the data looks like this.**
[image]

**And,I'm just training a model like so;**

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=5)
```

**But the errors happen like this**

Error when checking input: expected flatten_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (940682, 2)

How can I solve this problem?

And Here's the shape of X_train , y_train.
[image]

Comment: What is shape of the inputs (X_train, y_train)?

Comment: I just put a picture of shape X_train, y_train. Could you Please solve this problem? T-T

Comment: why did you use:  input_shape=(28, 28) as the input shape? if you have 2 columns the correct input shape is(2,)